# Eclipse Unable to read repository at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-mq-explorer-version-9

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-mq, mq

I am trying to install IBM MQ on Eclipse IDE (Photon) for Java Developers. There is a lot of information and help out there for being Unable to read a repository. I have gone to many of these resources, and none have seemed to help.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Is the url available from browser?

Comment: [1] Your post should provide more specific information. [2] I also see that error if I enter that URL in the **Work with** field on **Help > Install New Software**. [3] Can you update your post with a screen shot to show exactly what you are trying to install, and how you are doing it. [4] Check in Eclipse's Error Log (**Window > Show View > Others... > General > Error Log**) and update your post with any relevant errors.